# How do you grep/awk from a column in a file?

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a file of IDs called IDs_list.txt that I want to use in order to extract information from a second file which has hundreds of IDs, many of which are not in my specific IDS_list.txt.

I've tried combinations of if and grep but my results keep coming up empty.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do and what I've done.

```
cat IDS_list.txt | head -n 4
24
43
56
69

cat sample1.txt | head -n 4
NODE_1_length_148512_cov_24.5066,gi|573017271|gb|CP006568.1|,148512,4513140,8,7289,86.545,0.0,13461,24,madeup species 1
NODE_2_length_122550_cov_25.719,gi|84778498|dbj|AP008232.1|,122550,4171146,13,12690,93.693,0.0,23435,244,madeup species 2
NODE_3_length_103385_cov_25.9802,gi|84778498|dbj|AP008232.1|,103385,4171146,6,4243,88.782,0.0,7836,43,madeup species 3
NODE_4_length_101672_cov_25.6536,gi|84778498|dbj|AP008232.1|,101672,4171146,7,4139,86.799,0.0,7644,955,long name here
```

The IDs are in the 10th column.

I will need to pull out all lines where the IDs are in the IDS_list.txt.

So my output should be:

```
NODE_1_length_148512_cov_24.5066,gi|573017271|gb|CP006568.1|,148512,4513140,8,7289,86.545,0.0,13461,24,madeup species 1
NODE_3_length_103385_cov_25.9802,gi|84778498|dbj|AP008232.1|,103385,4171146,6,4243,88.782,0.0,7836,43,madeup species 3
```

I've tried:

```
for file in sample?.txt; do awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} ($10 in arr)' IDs_list.txt $file; done
```

Nothing comes out. This example I took from another stack overflow question.

```
for i in $(cat IDs_list.txt); do awk -F"," '$10 == $i' sample1.txt; done
```

But this will print a single output so many times because I am iterating over the IDs_list.txt line by line, so it is not what I want. I will get the first output line maybe hundreds of times because my IDs_list.txt has hundreds of IDs.

Then I tried grep with awk but that didn't work either. My syntax is off.

```
for file in sample?.txt; do for i in $(cat IDs_list.txt); do grep -w '$i' $file; done; done
```

Nothing is output here. My logic is that for each sample file, I want to grep the lines that contain the ID that is found in the IDs_list.txt. However I don't like not calling the specific 10th column because the IDs sometimes can show up in other columns that are not actually IDs.

Any eloquent way of doing this in a for loop with grep or awk or both somehow?

Comment: you reference `sample?.txt` which seems to indicate that you have multiple sample files ... do you need to keep the results separated per input file or do you want to consolidate the results of all the sample files into a single set of output lines? any requirement to keep track of the input file name? what about sorting the final output?

Comment: They need to be separated. Sorting would be fine too though the output should already come out sorted because the sample files are sorted by the Node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {ids[$1]; next} $10 in ids' IDs_list.txt sample.txt

NODE_1_length_148512_cov_24.5066,gi|573017271|gb|CP006568.1|,148512,4513140,8,7289,86.545,0.0,13461,24,madeup species 1
NODE_3_length_103385_cov_25.9802,gi|84778498|dbj|AP008232.1|,103385,4171146,6,4243,88.782,0.0,7836,43,madeup species 3
```

Comment: Nice! I knew it was something like my first command but I could not get the syntax down. still new to awk. This worked nicely and no need to even incorporate grep. Thanks!